# combining two taxonomy fields into one exposed filter dropdown

Tags: views

I have created two `taxonomy` fields (`home team` and `away team`) with a content type.

I have created a `views` to display the list content of content type. In view, I have added `taxonomy` filter for `home team` and `away team` which is showing two `taxonomy` filter in the views page.

I would like to combine both `taxonomy` filter into single exposed filter.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please put a bit of effort into your question. For example phrase title as a question, and use sentences in it's body. It'll make it easier to read for us non-native speakers. And showing a bit of effort you have put into solving it before you asked will greatly help, too. People aren't too eager to look for an answer if person who asked didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create only one taxonomy vocabulary like **Team Type**. Then add

> **home team** and **away team**

as terms in that vocabulary. Then add the new vocabulary as filter in view.

**OR**

Otherwise use form alter, then alter the dropdown field in the exposed for and set the options in the select field manullay.

Refer this: [How to alter filter in exposed filters form trough form_alter hook](https://drupal.org/node/364859)

Comment: 1st option wont work because home and  away team both are coming from teams only

Comment: you mean **home** and **away** are coming from a single vocabulary called **team**?

Comment: yes and filter having teams names dos'nt matter its a home team or away team

Comment: Please help me out i am i deep trouble

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this using below step:

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Views
- Edit your existing view or create new new.
- Add Filter for `taxonomy` for 'home' and 'away'
- Click on "Rearrange" filter icon in Filter section
- Click on "Create new filter group" and move filter "Home taxonomy" and "Away taxonomy" in new filter group.
- Select Operator as "Or" in new filter group and save the form.

[image: Views filter]

Comment: but there should be only one dropdown a combination of home and away team

Comment: i tried global:combine filter but it coming in search form i need a dropdown

Comment: please help me i am i deep trouble

Comment: @mayur, I have worked on this but with other scenario. I am working on this and will let you know.

Comment: @mayur please help yourself and 1) read my comment under your question, 2) review suggested edit by Jayendra Kainthola and either accept it, or not, but if not, then do some cleanup yourself so we could be sure we know what you need.

Comment: please help me??

Comment: @mayur, I am looking into this. If I found anything, I will let you know.